# table cell showing white border in outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook

I am trying to build a newsletter. However when i import my html into outlook, i see a very strange white border is appended by outlook to my images. e.g. here is the button having left and right white borders, and i cant remove it

[image: white border around image in outlook]

The code is

```
<table id="__02" height="44" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" width="463" style=”line-height:44px;”>
            <img border="0" src="images/index_03.png" width="463" height="44" alt=""></td>
        <td align="left" width="183" style=”line-height:44px;”>
            <img border="0" src="images/index_04.png" width="183" height="44" alt=""></td>
        <td align="left" width="334" style=”line-height:44px;”>
            <img border="0" src="images/index_05.png" width="334" height="44" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and the css i have tried

```
table, td, img{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
img {display:block;margin:0;padding:0;}
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the correct answer but have you tried?

```
img{border:0;}
```

I know it used to be an issue for some browsers but not sure if this has been corrected in outlook

The only other thing I can suggest is change the table, td, img border to 0

```
table, td, img{
    border:0;
}
```

Comment: hi, it is not working, as i already did <img border="0", thanks